# If $A$ is a matrix with rank($A$)=1,then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is of degree $2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, matrix-rank, minimal-polynomials

> If  $n \ge 2$ and if  $A$ is a matrix with rank($A$)=1,then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is of degree $2$.

So, we see that $rank (A) =1$.So, nullity of $A \ge 1$.Now we try to find the range space of $A$.If $y \in R(A)$ then $A(x)=y$.

We see that null space  of $A$ is being spanned by $n-1$ linearly independent vectors. We can extend this to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be the basis where $x_1,..,x_{n-1} \in ker(A)$.We see that $x_n$ must not be in ker($A$) otherwise $A$ is the zero matrix so that $A=0$.

Let $x_n$ be the vector which spans the range space Of $A$ such that $A(\sum(c_ix_i))=x_n$ where $1 \le i \le n$.So from here we can conclude that $0,(c_n)^{-1}$ are the only eigenvalues values. Hence the minimal polynomial becomes $x(x-(c_n)^{-1})$ .

Comment: The initial question introduces $n$ and then never uses it. Supposedly $A$ is a square matrix of size$~n$, but if so please say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ a basis such that $(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$ is a basis of $ker A$ and $x_n$ a basis of $Im A$. We have $A(x_n)=cx_n$, $c\neq 0$ since $A\neq 0$. Write $P=X(X-c)$, $P(A)(e_i)=(A-cI)(A(x_i)=0$ if $i<n$. $P(A)(x_n)=A(A-cI)(x_n)=0$. Implies that $P(A)=0$.

Comment: @Guria Sona: Note that this argument shows that the minimal polynomial must divide $X(X-c)$. However, it is easy to argue that it cannot be of degree one since $n \geq 2$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 1$ so $A$ is not a multiple of the identity matrix (since a multiple of the identity matrix has either rank $0$ or rank $n$).

Comment: $[0, 1: 0, 0]$ is rank $1$ matrix without non-zero eigenvalue. What about such case?

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be easily shown(without assuming the concept of diagonalizability) by using the result that **Algebraic multiplicity of an eigen value is greater than or equal to its geometric multiplicity** and by case wise determining the Ch eqn and min polynomial.
**Proof**: Suppose, $T:V\to V$ corresponding to the $n\times n$ matrix $A$, where $V$ is an **'n'** dimensional vector space. $\beta$ be the standard basis i.e,  $[T]_{\beta}=A$. Now from rank-nullity theorem,
$dim(Ker T)=(n-1)$(say), Assumed $\beta$ be the extended basis of this.  [since, $dim(V)=n$ and $dim(Im T)=rank(A)=1$(given)]
Now, **$A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with rank $1$ where $n\geq 2$**, so, $det(A)=0$. Since, $A$ is matrix of order $n$ , the characteristic eqn, $det(xI-A)=0$ is of degree $n$. Here, $det(A)=0$ so "$0$" is an eigen value because $x=0$ satisfies the ch. eqn. Now trying to find the geometric multiplicity of the eigen value $0$, i.e the dimension of the solution space of $(A-0.I)x=0$ i.e, $\to Ax=0$, which is same with $dim(Ker T)=(n-1)$. So, the eigen value $0$ has geometric multiplicity $(n-1)$. So, the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is $\geq (n-1)$. Since Characteristic eqn of degree $n$ of the matrix $A$ will look like
i) $x^n=0$  or,
ii) $[x^{(n-1)}\times (x-c)]=0$  , where, $c\neq 0$, the other eigen value.
Now $x^n=0$ cannot be the Ch eqn for all such matrix $A$ , here is the contradictory example ,
take $A=$ $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$, a $2\times 2$ matrix of rank $1$ , here $x^2=0$ is not the Ch eqn. Check the Ch eqn is $x(x-5)=0$, which is of second type. As we have only two possibilities of Ch eqn then we can conclude that,            **The Ch eqn of such matrix $A$ (as given) is $[x^{(n-1)}\times (x-c)]=0$  , $c\neq 0$.**

Now $(x-c)=0$ is not the minimal polynomial, because for all such $A$, $(A-cI)\neq 0$, we can assume that same contradictory example again to get contradiction s.t for $A=$ $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$ (rank=$1$ & order=$2$), $(A-5I)\neq 0$.And also since $rank(A)=1$ $\to$ $A\neq 0$ so $x=0$ is not the minimal polynomial.

Now we will check if the matrix $A$ can satisfy $x(x-c)=0$.  Now $c$ is an non-zero eigen value having algebraic and geometric multiplicity $=1$. So,  the dimension of the solution space of $(A-c.I)x=0$ is $1$, $x\epsilon V$.So, $dim(Ker(A-c.I))=1$ $\to$ $dim(Im(A-c.I))=(n-1)$
[Since, $(A-c.I)$ is $n\times n$ matrix $\simeq$ $T':V\to V]$. So, $rank(A-c.I)=(n-1)$ and $rank(A)=1$ , so $rank(A(A-c.I))=1$ or, $0$ [as, $r(AB)\leq min (r(A),r(B))$].
If $rank(A(A-c.I))=0$ then $A(A-c.I)=0$.
If $rank(A(A-c.I))=1$ we have $(A(A-c.I))$ is $n\times n$ matrix $\simeq$ $T'':V\to V$, so $dim(Ker(T''))=(n-1)$, we can easily check $x\epsilon Ker(T)$ $\to$ $x\epsilon Ker(T'')$ and dimension same so, $Ker(T)=Ker(T'')$. Now, there exist non zero $x$ $\epsilon$ $Ker(T')$ [As $dim(Ker(T'))=dim(Ker(A-c.I))=1$], then $(A-c.I)x=0$ $\to$ $Ax=cx\neq 0$ so, $x$ does not belong to $Ker(T)$, but $A(A-c.I)x=A^2x-cAx=A(cx)-c^2x=c^2x-c^2x=0$, so $x$ $\epsilon$ $Ker(T'')$ , So, $Ker(T)\neq Ker(T'')$ , hence a contradiction. So, $A(A-c.I)=0$ and $x(x-c)=0$ be the minimal polynomial of degree $2$ for all such $A$ (as given). [Hence proved]

I have tried to do in a new way with the basic concepts only.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with the way your solution is written. You start with $n - 1$ linearly independent vectors $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}$ which span the null space of $A$ and say that you extend them to a basis $x_1, \dots, x_{n}$ of $\mathbb{F}^n$. A priori, if this extension is performed arbitrary there is no reason that $x_n$ will span the range of $A$. You need to argue that if you pick a non-zero element $x_n$ of the range space of $A$, then $x_1, \dots, x_n$ will be linearly independent and so will form a basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$. Then $Ax_1 = \dots = Ax_{n-1} = 0$ while $Ax_n = cx_n$ for some $c \in \mathbb{F}$ (because the range space is one-dimesional). This shows that $0$ and $c$ are the only eigenvalues of $A$ and since $0$ has an $n-1$ dimensional eigenspace and $c$ has a one-dimensional eigenspace, this means that those are the **only** eigenvalues and so the **characteristic** polynomial of $A$ is $x^{n-1}(x - c)$.

Finally, you somehow "deduce" from the fact that there are only two eigenvalues that the **minimal** polynomial is $x(x-c)$ but you need to justify this. The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial but a priori it can be $x^2(x-c)$ or $x - c$ and so on. Why is it precisely $x(x-c)$? One way is to say that $A$ is **diagonalizable** and so the minimal polynomial is the product of the linear factors which are associated to the distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, I agree. My intuition has been to show that there are n distinct eigenvectors then from that it can be said that $A$ is diagonalizable so the minimal polynomial is of degree $2$ as the way I have proved. Yes, I should have written it down carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. $(n\geq 2)$

Since rank is equal to $1$, nullity is $n-1$.

That is geometric multiplicity(GM) of eigenvalue $0$ is $n-1$.

Since for any eigenvalue, algebraic multiplicity(AM) is greater than or equal to geometric multiplicity, AM$(0)\geq n-1$.

Case $1$: When AM$(0)=n-1$:

So there is one non-zero eigenvalue, say $c$, with AM equal to 1, and thus GM also equal to $1$.

Therefore, for all the eigenvalues of $A$, we have AM$=$GM, so $A$ is diagonalizable. That means $m_A(x)$ is product of distinct linear factors, which is nothing but $x(x-c)$.

Case $2$: When AM$(0)=n$

Since GM$(0)=n-1$, in JC form of $A$, there are $n-1$ jordan blocks of eigenvalue $0$, in which exactly one block will be of size $2$ and other blocks will be of size $1$, which immediately leads to $m_A(x)=x^2$.